# VS Database project generated bad script on run

Tags: visual-studio-2013, database-project

I have a visual studio 2013 database project and when I deploy (as part of running a project in the solution) I get this error:
"Line 6 Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss might occur."

I have found the offending line in the sql script.

The SQL Script is trying to change a column type from NVarchar to Varchar.  But it does not need to do this - it's already Varchar in the database.

This works when I publish from the database project.  It does not have a line for changing the column types.  That's because it has already run and change the columns.  There is no need to change the columns now.

But when I run (ctrl-F5) it builds my solution and tries to deploy.  This is when I get the error.

1) Why does it deploy when I run?  I can't find the setting and it does not happen to other developers on the same project.  It must be a visual studio setting.

2) What connectString would it be using when it deploys from a run?  Perhaps it's getting a connect string from another database instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it deploy when I run?

Check Configuration Manager (Build menu > Configuration Manager). The Deploy checkbox is probably checked for the database project.

> What connectString would it be using when it deploys from a run?

The connection string defined in the Debug tab in the project properties.